# Show location every 10 seconds in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm doing an app in which every 10 seconds the location appears in a different place on the map, the bad thing is that it does not work for me and when I run the program I see all the locations already in place. but I want that every 10 seconds go by placing one by one as if they were moving.
This is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    for ( contador=1;contador<=10;contador++) {

            final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

               handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
            }
        }, EXECUTION_TIME);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador), 17));

    }
}
```

any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handlers do nothing but launching other handlers, you have to make the `addMarker` and `moveCamera` calls inside the `run()` and at the end of the `run()` launch the next `postDelayed`. You can use a int to count and see where you are in the loop and launch another handler only if this int is under 10. (here i used `cpt` to do that)

```
final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    int cpt = 1;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* old
        * mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        * mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador), 17));
        */
        //new
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(cpt)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(cpt), 17));

        cpt++;
        if(cpt <= 10)
            handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
    }
}, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Comment: I put it like you did and just leave the point once. I tried to put it in a while loop, so that I can mark the rest but do nothing. I want you to dial 10 times but only mark the first

Comment: i(m not sure about what you want, if you just want to move the camera 10 times, just put the `addMarker` call outside of the handler, by the way i didn't update it but you might want my `cpt` variable to be `countador` so when you call `obtenerLatLong()`, it actualy loop from 1 to 10

Comment: Yes, precisely that cpt is like a counter, for each turn display a new marker on the map.
only that when adding the while cycle, it does everything to me at once, it is as if it is not respecting the time of 10 seconds for each marker.

Comment: i edited my code to use `cpt` everywhere, try it without putting it in a while loop

Answer (score 0):

This will work try it :

```
final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
int i=0;
  @Override
  public void run() {
    i=i+1;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador), 17));
    if(i==10){
       handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
 }
}, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Comment: But how do I know if I performed 10 times? I think a cycle is needed, just as I was in the question.

Comment: int i=0; // this is taken to know the cycle is performed 10 times.

Comment: if(i==10) // check the cycle have performed 10 times then  remove cycle by calling -> handler.removeCallbacks(this);

Comment: try and change according to you it will work. let me know if face any issue.

Comment: I put it like you did and just leave the point once. I tried to put it in a while loop, so that I can mark the rest but do nothing.

Comment: I want you to dial 10 times but only mark the first